# Bloquear rolagem do scroll pelas telas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

como que bloqueia a rolagem do scroll da pagina pelas teclas com jquery, tecla cima(38) e tecla baixo(40),  deixando a rolagem apenas pelo mouse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suponho que esteja falando de qualquer elemento menos textarea, inputs e selects, se for então pode usar regex ou ifs pra verificar o elemento combinado com `event.target`:

```
/^(textarea|input|select)$/i
```

```js
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    var key = evt.keyCode;
    if ((key === 38 || key === 40) && !/^(textarea|input|select)$/i.test(evt.target.tagName)) {
       return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea>teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste</textarea>


Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br>
```

Se quiser bloquear de qualquer um:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    var key = evt.keyCode;
    if (key === 38 || key === 40) {
       return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea>teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste</textarea>

Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br>
```

### Vanilla.js

```js
(function () {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", blockSrollByKeys, false);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("onkeydown", blockSrollByKeys);
    }

    function blockSrollByKeys(evt) {
        var key = evt.keyCode;
      
        if ((key === 38 || key === 40) && !/^(textarea|input|select)$/i.test(evt.target.tagName)) {
           evt.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<textarea>teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste
teste teste</textarea>

Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br> Teste <br>
```

Comment: era isso mesmo, me ajudou bastante u.u